# Is there a way to disable react-refresh-webpack-plugin on a specific entry?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I have mutiple entries, such as pageA and pageB. They render in different html. So I don't want to pageB get refresh when I was edit components used in pageA.

```
entry: {
  pageA: "./src/pageA.js"
  pageB: "./src/pageB.js"
}
```